# Cannot chain .join() method onto Math.pow to change array back to integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, scope

Hello I am practising a code wars kata and I do not understand why I cannot chain `.join` to `Math.pow`.

Here are the instructions:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/546e2562b03326a88e000020/train/javascript

Welcome. In this kata, you are asked to square every digit of a number and concatenate them.
For example, if we run 9119 through the function, 811181 will come out, because 92 is 81 and 12 is 1.

Here is my code:
I have converted the number passed in to an array so i can iterate over it with `.map` and  square each element. Then I want to join the result of my map back together but it doesn't work...

```
function squareDigits(num){  
  const convertNumToArray = Array.from(String(num));
  return convertNumToArray.map((num) => {
  return Math.pow(num,2).join("")    
  })
}
```

here is the test case:

```
Test.assertEquals(squareDigits(9119), 811181);
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Math.pow(...).join is not a function
    at convertNumToArray.map
    at Array.map
    at squareDigits
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:21:23
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:23:5
    at Object.handleError
```

Comment: `Math.pow()` returns a number. The `.join("")` has to be called on the result of `.map()` -> `.map((num) => /*...*/).join("")`

Comment: So do I need to store the `.map`  in a variable? and then call `.join` on the variable? I tried and it still didn't work i'll try again @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer

```
function squareDigits(num){
  return Number(String(num).split('').map((c)=>c*c).join(''))
}
```

Comment: @ubaidah ok so you recommend not using `Math.pow` at all. I see you have wrapped the whole thing in Number so it returns a number then you split the argument passed in and map over it. I didn't know you could iterate over a string with `.map`

Comment: ok now I just found this article and it explains that `.split` parses a string into an `array`... you learn something new every day : https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-iterate-over-the-characters-of-a-string-in-JavaScript

Comment: your answer is almost right but you are trying to attach join on the number if you remove join there and put it when you are returning the array like this   ```   function squareDigits(num){  
  const convertNumToArray = Array.from(String(num));
  return convertNumToArray.map((num) => {
  return Math.pow(num,2) 
  }).join("")   
}  ```

Comment: Ar I see, so I wasn't far off. I see your code is a lot cleaner though. I had to also wrap the above in "Number" so that it returned a number - THANK YOU!!!

Comment: codewars is a great place to practice and improve your skills .thank you

Answer (score 2):

As @Andreas pointed out in the comments, you need to apply [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to the result of [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not `Math.pow`, which does not return an array. Using ES6 arrow functions you can write this in one line:

```js
const squareDigits = (num) =>
  Array
  .from(String(num))
  .map((digit) => Math.pow(digit, 2))
  .join('');

console.log(squareDigits(9119));
console.log(squareDigits(573));
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I didn't realised i'd have to do it as an arrow function i see in your `console.log` it returns a number but when I run my code in the kata terminal, it returns '811181' as a string, I now need to see where I do the conversion of this function back to a number! :)

Comment: actually when I run it in my terminal I get a number back, it must be the codeWars terminal that is causing the error `Expected: 811181, instead got: '811181'` this is what i see.. @Nick

Comment: Sorry,  It wasn't clear you had to return a number, you could just wrap all the code in a Number.  Note it's not necessary to use an arrow function,  I just find them easier to read.

Comment: OK thank you i'll do that. Yes I find your code easier to read too!